# CKEditor displaying &undefined; after certain characters added to config.entities_adddtional

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

We have a CMS using CKEditor 4 with WYSIWYG and source HTML views.  We are trying to add more symbols that are not in the Greek and Latin sets.

Specifically, we're trying to add characters like this.

[image: Mathematical N Script]

from https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

In the CKEditor Javascript config code, I added this field.

```
config.entities_additional='#119977';
```

In the CKEditor in WYSIWYG mode, I paste the actual 'N' glyph into the textarea, and then click the "Source" button, which switch to HTML mode.  I noticed that it looks like this: `<p>&#119977;&undefined;</p>`  Every time I toggle between WYSIWYG and Source, it keeps adding another `&undefined;` at the end.  Example after 3 toggles: `<p>&#119977;&undefined;&undefined;&undefined;</p>`

Does anybody know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CKEditor 4.8.0 can't parse 16-bit glyphs like the one in my example.

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding